# wrong results with analytic functions in hive

Tags: hiveql

I am trying to use analytic functions with partitioning clause in hive but getting wrong results.
for example, the data is as follows

```
col1    col2
a       1
a       2
a       3
d       1
d       2
e       1
e       2
```

dense_rank() over(partition by col1,col2) 
is giving 1 as result for all rows.
do we have to enable analytic functions with some set options?
do the underlying table need to be partitioned?
i am using hive on cdh 5

Comment: The result seems correct, each partition (col1, col2) contains one row only in your example. What results do you expect?

Comment: Partition a, 1 has the only row, rank=1; partition a,2 has one row, rank=1. and so on. Absolutely correct result